# SQL: derive values based on inputs

Tags: sql, db2

table transactions : business_key = customer_id

```
customer_id|product_type|amount
-------------------------------
cus1       | shoes      | 100
cus1       | shoes      |  50
cus1       | clothes    | 100
cus2       | clothes    | 500
cus2       |clothes     |  21
```

table transactionsbycustomer: business_key = customer_id + product_type

```
customer_id|product_type|amount
-------------------------------
cus1       |shoes       |150
cus1       |clothes     | 50
cus2       |clothes     |521
```

I need to derive values for *amount* in 'transactionsbycustomer' table using SQL? Please help!

Comment: You mean something like: 'SELECT amount FROM transactionsbycustomer WHERE customer_id = "cus1"';? What do you specifically need?

Comment: please add an example of the expected output based on the sample data.

Comment: I guess you are thinking about the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic SQL.

```
SELECT customer_id, product_id, sum(amount) as total
FROM transactionsbycustomers
GROUP BY customer_id, product_id
```